# Best way to import numeric and non-numeric data (string) from an excel file into MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I want to know the best way of importing both number and non-numeric data (which is string in the present case) from an excel file into MATLAB? By best (or better) way, I mean all the data together in a variable (or data structure).

First, I tried *uiopen(filename)* function which opens a wizard and from there, I can import the data into a MATLAB variable. However, problem here is that it replaces all the non-numeric data with zeros which is not required. I later on, found that this function calls another function, named *xlsread(filename)*, which is another way (actual way) of importing excel file.

Second (last) way that I tried (which seems to be better) is to use function called *importdata(filename)* which imports both numeric and non-numeric data into separate structure variables.

However, I am wondering if there exists some other way(s) to import everything into a single variable or data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlsread` is the correct way to import data from Excel spreadsheets,both numeric and non-numeric data. Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html):

> `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(___)` additionally returns the text fields in
>   cell array `txt`, and the unprocessed data (numbers and text) in cell
>   array `raw` using any of the input arguments in the previous syntaxes.
>   If `xlRange` is specified, leading blank rows and columns in the
>   worksheet that precede rows and columns with data are returned in `raw`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got it what I wanted in 'raw' variable.